# MVC multiple checkbox values to string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm trying to get multiple checkbox values and then pass them into another property as one string.

In my view I have the following to get the checkbox values:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Consent.ConsentToPost, new { @class = "consentGiven" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Consent.ConsentToEmail, new { @class = "consentGiven" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Consent.ConsentToTelephone, new { @class = "consentGiven" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Consent.ConsentToTextMessage, new { @class = "consentGiven" })
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Consent.ConsentNotGiven, new { @class = "consentNotGiven" })
```

Then in my model i am currently trying to create an array called Consent and then convert that to a string to pass it through the Additional Details property as one string:

```
public List<Consent> Consent { get; set; }

public override CallbackDetails ConvertToDto()
{
  var callbackDetails = base.ConvertToDto();
  callbackDetails.Postcode = Postcode;
  callbackDetails.AdditionalDetail = Consent.ToString();
  return callbackDetails; <---- Error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'xxxxxx.Models.Consent' to 'string'---
}


public class Consent {
   public bool ConsentNotGiven { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToPost { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToEmail { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToTelephone { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToTextMessage { get; set; }
}
```

In my callbackDetails model I have the additional details property:

```
public string AdditionalDetail { get; set; }
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is your error? You've just put "Error"?!!!

Comment: Why? And what would the result of the `string` be?

Comment: I'm getting 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'xxxxxx.Models.Consent' to 'string'. Not sure if it helps but I will update my question with the separate additional details property also

Comment: Where are you calling that. And it makes no sense - all that could possibly return is "System.Generic.Collections.List[Consent]"

Comment: What is the `CallbackDetails` declared? `Consent.ToString()` will return typename of `List<Consent>`, if you need values inside that list use iteration with `foreach` loop. I still not understand why you're passing typename instead of list values.

Comment: I could be going around it the wrong way but what I basically require is all the values from the checkboxes to be 'injected' in the additional details property

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to override toString method of Consent class?

```
public class Consent {
   public bool ConsentNotGiven { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToPost { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToEmail { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToTelephone { get; set; }
   public bool ConsentToTextMessage { get; set; }


   public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ConsentNotGiven.toString() + " || " + this.ConsentToPost.toString() + " || " + this.ConsentToEmail.toString() + " || " + this.ConsentToTelephone.toString() + " || " + this.ConsentToTextMessage.toString();
    }
}
```